# How do I pass the password to a net use command without being prompted?

Tags: command-line, passwords

I need to map a drive without being prompted for the password.  I am trying to use net use and putting the password inline within the command.  I get an error.

```
net use H: \\MYSERVER\MYFOLDERS\Backup /user:ABCCompany\JoeUser oasddkjkla
```

I get the following error: 'sddkj' is not recognized as an internal or external command.  If it's not obvious, it's a part of the password that I entered.

The command works fine if I remove the password and enter it upon the dialog box.  I'm using Windows 10.  Is it still acceptable to pass the password right after the username?

Comment: The command above looks correct to me. when writing your batch file, what program did you use?

Comment: As I read the documentation, the password should follow the network share address.

Comment: @Stese I used both the command window and a SQL Server cmd call.  Both returned the same error.

Comment: @AFH Can you point me to the documentation you read?

Comment: Type `net use /?`. or look [here](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please try using:

```
net use H: \\MYSERVER\MYFOLDERS\Backup oasddkjkla /user:ABCCompany\JoeUser
```

Answer (score 11):

`net use w: \\myserver\fileshare /user:MyID MyPassword`

If you have a space in the password you need to put it in quotes, for example:

`net use w: \\myserver\fileshare /user:"tom jone" "go to it"`